# Animate scroll to div inside parallax site

Tags: java, jquery, scroll, parallax, animated

I have a few links at the top of my parallax page, and I want them to animate scroll to the desired place in the page when you click on them.  Currently the links just jump to places on my page, no animation.

The parallax scrolling is working, which is the first piece of code in my .js file that can be viewed at the bottom of the page.

here is my links div

```
<div id="main-nav"> <!-- top locked scroll bar -->
        <p>
        <a class="click" href="#home">Your Links</a> |
        <a href="#me">More Links</a> |
        <a href="#projects">Another Link</a> |
        <a href="#hire">Really</a> 
       <!-- <button onclick="changeColor()">Yin/Yang</button> -->
        </p>
    </div>
```

an example of where it jumps to on the page (but I want it to animate to)

```
section class="box slide slide-1">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="home"></div>
      <h1>Main Title</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
```

here is all of the javascript I'm using on the page

```
(function(){

var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
  speed = 0.5;

window.onscroll = function(){
[].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(p,i){

  var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
      theBackgrounPos = "0 " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";

  p.style.backgroundPosition = theBackgrounPos;

 });
 };
 })();

 /************ CODE USED TO MAKE THE ANIMATION SCROLL TO THAT IS NOT WORKING*////
 $(document).ready(function (){
       $(".click").click(function (){
               $('html, body').animate({
                   scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top
               }, 2000);
       });
 });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if my best route is starting over.

Comment: www.littleroomproductions.com/simple         link to the code in action where the animation isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I just got the following running on a site I'm working on.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[href^='#']").click(function(event) {
        var target = $($(this).attr("href"));
        event.preventDefault();
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 500);
    });    
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav-menu">
    <a href="#home"><p>home</p></a>
    <a href="#services"><p>services</p></a>
    <a href="#work"><p>work</p></a>
    <a href="#about"><p>about</p></a>
    <a href="#contact"><p>contact</p></a>
</nav>
```

And then divs down the page with "id=home", "id=services", etc.

Comment: just tried that code and it still just jumps.  Is your javascript inside of something?

Comment: The JavaScript is in an external file. I added above what the code is wrapped in: $(document.ready(function() { ... });

Comment: Could also put it in the HTML wrapped by <script>...</script>

Comment: added another script page   [  scroll.js    ]   and put that script in it - no go :(

Comment: Hmmm... You can try adding an "alert("Lemon Curry?");" or something inside after the "event.preventDefault();" to see if the click function is getting called. Seems like the jumps are still happening because of the <a> link (which should be disabled by event.preventDefult()).